# get the index of a child view in android

Tags: android, parent-child

I have a TableRow that contains TextViews. When a TextView is clicked, a method receives the the TextView. Is there a way to know if this TextView is the first, second, or i'th child of its parent view?

Thanks

Comment: TextViews were added programmatically?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First you need to get a reference to the parent view with .getParent(). Having the parent you can use indexOfChild(myView) to get the index of your view within the parent. In one row it looks like this:

```
int indexOfMyView = ((TableRow ) myView.getParent()).indexOfChild(myView);
```

This should work with any type of parent view:

```
int indexOfMyView = ((ViewGroup) myView.getParent()).indexOfChild(myView);
```

Comment: Add some explanation in answer which make it more useful for OP or for others for same issue.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In `onclicklistener`, Get the parent of `TextView`

```
TableRow r = (TableRow) ((ViewGroup) textView.getParent());
int position = r.indexOfChild(textView)
```

Hope this helps